# modify tibble to use better facet labels

Tags: r, dplyr

I have attached a sample code below. `a` is categorical variable with `0` and `1` but number of factor levels can be dynamic.

1. Someone please modify the tibble to add another column which has values `a = 0` and `a = 1`. So that I can use this column for faceting in ggplot for better facet labels.
2. Also change sequence of facets in ggplot i.e. panel `a = 1` should be above `a = 0`

Thanks

```
library(tidyverse)

# continuous variables
x1 <- seq(-5, 5, 0.1)

# compute y1
error_term <- runif(1, min = -2, max = 2)
y1 <- 1/(1 + exp(-x1 + error_term))

# compute y2
error_term <- runif(1, min = -2, max = 2)
y2 <- 1/(1 + exp(-x1 + error_term))

# merge x and y
y <- c(y1, y2)
x <- c(x1, x1)

# categorical variable
a <- c(rep(0, 101), rep(1, 101))

# tibble 
tbl <- tibble(x, a, y)

# GGPLOT ---------------------------------------------------------------------
p <- ggplot(data = tbl,
                    aes(x = x,
                        y = y,
                        color = factor(a))) + 
  geom_line() + 
  theme_bw() +
  facet_grid(a ~ .) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be achieved like so:

1. Set the order via `levels` argument of `factor`
2. Change the labels via the `labels` argument of `factor`

```r
library(tidyverse)

# continuous variables
x1 <- seq(-5, 5, 0.1)

# compute y1
error_term <- runif(1, min = -2, max = 2)
y1 <- 1/(1 + exp(-x1 + error_term))

# compute y2
error_term <- runif(1, min = -2, max = 2)
y2 <- 1/(1 + exp(-x1 + error_term))

# merge x and y
y <- c(y1, y2)
x <- c(x1, x1)

# categorical variable
a <- c(rep(0, 101), rep(1, 101))

# tibble 
tbl <- tibble(x, a, y)

tbl <- mutate(tbl, a = factor(a, levels = c(1, 0), labels = paste0("a = ", c(1, 0))))

ggplot(data = tbl,
            aes(x = x,
                y = y,
                color = a)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  theme_bw() +
  facet_grid(a ~ .) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @stefan